# asp.net core behind nginx with http2 - remote ip always 127.0.0.1

Tags: nginx, asp.net-core, ip-address, http2

I have an asp.net net core 2.0 app hosted behind Nginx on Ubuntu 16.04.

my settings look like that:

```
server {
        listen 443 ssl http2; 
        listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
        ssl on;
...
    location / {
                    proxy_pass http://localhost:5000;
                    proxy_http_version 1.1;
                    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                    proxy_set_header Connection keep-alive;
                    proxy_set_header Host $host;
                    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
                    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto-Version $http2;
                    client_max_body_size 32m;
                    keepalive_timeout 200;
                    send_timeout 20;
                    client_body_timeout 50;
            }
}
```

and I also have these settings in `Startup.cs`

```
app.UseForwardedHeaders(new ForwardedHeadersOptions
            {
                ForwardedHeaders = ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedFor |
                                   ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedProto
            });
```

But still every time when I trying to get `HttpContext.Connection.RemoteIpAddress` it's return `127.0.0.1`

What should I do to fix this and get the real IP address?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

ok, find answer myself.

this line unneeded (however seems like don't do anything harmful)

```
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto-Version $http2;
```

but we need to say to Nginx to set `X-Forwarded-For` header with this line:

**`proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;`**

Comment: The reference to your answer: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/linux-nginx?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=aspnetcore2x